# cypress select with error message Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.select() failed because it could not find a single <option> with value

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, cypress

using Cypress for a test script I can not for what ever reason select a year. A very simple task.

The threads on cypress / select I found did not help me so far.

**HTML part**:

```
 <select id='actual_year' name='akt_year' class='form-select form-control-lg' onchange='aktion_changed(2)'><option value='-1' selected>Please choose a year</option>
   <option  value = '2025'>2025</option>
   <option  value = '2024'>2024</option>
   <option selected value = '2023'>2023</option>
    </select>
```

**CYPRESS JAVASCRIPT TEST SCRIPTS**:

objectFile.js :

```
selectYear(yearYYYY){
        cy.get('#actual_year').select(yearYYYY)
}
```

testFile.js :

For the actual year of 2023 I use this:

```
let actualYear = new Date().getFullYear();
onFormPage.selectYear(actualYear)
```

**CYPRESS ERROR**:

**Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.select() failed because it could not find a single  with value, index, or text matching: 2023**

**cy.get('#actual_year').select(yearYYYY)**

With the marker at "s" of select.

I tried this validation and it works:

```
cy.get('#actual_year').contains(actualYear)
```

So it can read the element and the select entry.

Cypress Documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select

Standard expression:
`cy.get('select').select('user-1')` // Select the 'user-1' option

Cypress Version: v12.14.0

How ever it does not select the year.
I have many selects that work with the same easy expression like from the cypress documentation but not in this case.
Why?

Does anyone has an idea?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is casued by the variable type.

`.getFullYear()` returns a number, but Cypress checks this against the `value` attribute and the text content, and both of those are string types.

It will succeed if you `.toString()` the year passed in.

```js
let actualYear = new Date().getFullYear()
cy.get('#actual_year').select(actualYear.toString())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Case closed.